# Are there any differences between Paragraph Shading and Paragraph atop Color?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, paragraph-styles

Alright so new feature of InDesign CC 2015 is Paragraph Shading. A long overdue feature. The question is for Print Projects is there any difference between using Shading vs the old way of putting a colored box below the text?

Here is my Paragraph Shade panel:

[image: Shading Panel]

Here is a closeup of PDF export using the Shade function:

[image: Shade Function]

Here is a closeup of PDF export using the box method:

[image: Shade Function]

I don't see any differences from a visual standpoint, (the area under my box is on a gray background) but before I implement this on print projects thought I'd ask and see what, if any, differences there are to consider when using Paragraph Shading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing to worry about in terms of output.

All that's being done is the text frame is getting a color applied to it. It's no different than placing a colored rectangle behind the text frame. Output would be the same, it's only the production method that is changing (and is easier).

Comment: Easier in some instances. I'm actually working on an ad so probably easier to just keep using the box method. In a larger publication where styles are relevant it would certainly be easier to implement this.

Comment: Yeah it'll all depend on the actual layout but a color applied to a paragraph is essentially the same as if you applied a color to the text frame... or used the box method. It all outputs the same.